# How do I get the min/max of columns in table A and values from B where the rows of B are determined by another column in A?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to understand how to write my query so that for some of the columns it returns the values where other columns have minimum or maximum values, while returning the min/max of those columns.

I have two Postgresql tables containing drives (trips with my car) and street adresses, and I want to select data from them to group drives together into trips. For instance, going from my house to the store is a drive, going back again is another drive, and grouping the two together forms one single trip. For each such grouped trip I want to get the start time and address of the first drive, the end time and position of the final drive, and the sums of all drive times and distances.

This is an example query for getting three drives which I want to combine into a trip:

```
SELECT
    start_time,
    end_time,
    duration,
    distance,
    start_address.name AS start_address,
    end_address.name AS end_address
FROM drives
    LEFT JOIN addresses start_address ON start_address_id = start_address.id
    LEFT JOIN addresses end_address ON end_address_id = end_address.id
WHERE drives.id=ANY('{10, 11, 12}');
```

Running this query might produce the following result:

```
row# | start_time | end_time   | duration | distance | start_address | end_address
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      14:40:00     14:43:00     3          0.75       Home            The store
2      14:48:00     14:58:00     10         2.25       The store       Post office
3      15:10:00     15:08:00     8          2.00       Post office     Work
```

Now, I want to construct one single query that should result in one row representing the combined trip of those three drives. I want the row to contain the minimum start time, the maximum end time, the sum of the durations, the sum of the distances, the start address from the row that had the minimum start time and the end address of the row that had the maximum end time.

If I omit the address parts, it's straightforward:

```
SELECT
    min(start_time) AS start_time,
    max(end_time) AS end_time,
    sum(duration) AS duration,
    sum(distance) AS distance
FROM drives
WHERE drives.id=ANY('{10, 11, 12}');
```

```
row# | start_time | end_time   | duration | distance
----------------------------------------------------
1      14:40:00     15:08:00     21          5.00
```

But how do I write my query so that I also get the addresses? I want this result:

```
row# | start_time | end_time   | duration | distance | start_address | end_address
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      14:40:00     15:08:00     21          5.00      Home            Work
```

Obviously I need to get the address parts back into the query, but no matter what I try I can't figure out how to construct it correctly. Frankly, I'm not even sure I got the title of this question right :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use window function `first_value` and `last_value` in the main query and then aggregate with one level sub query as,

```
SELECT
    min(start_time) AS start_time,
    max(end_time) AS end_time,
    sum(duration) AS duration,
    sum(distance) AS distance,
    max(start_address) start_address,
    max(end_address) end_address  
FROM
(
    SELECT
        start_time,
        end_time,
        duration,
        distance,
        first_value(start_address.name) over (order by start_time,end_time) start_address,
        last_value(end_address.name) over (order by start_time,end_time rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) end_address
    FROM drives
        LEFT JOIN addresses start_address ON start_address_id = start_address.id
        LEFT JOIN addresses end_address ON end_address_id = end_address.id
    WHERE drives.id=ANY('{10, 11, 12}')
) c;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add a name to the inner select (just added "as foo" before the semicolon) for the query to succeed. It produced the wanted data except for the end address; both the start and end addresses are taken from the first drive (in my example, the trip is reported to go from Home -> The store).

Comment: i was hoping It should work. the `order by` is important here, Could you check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=148ba459d3720d204cac6572fb955099) where it seems to be working. Or else could you try with the main query by putting `order by start_time,end_time` and see the result if the expected `start_address.name` and `end_address.name` are coming in first and last row respectively.

Comment: I have simulated the complete one. Please check [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cfc4cc4a5600c81fce3b14ed9a4a5043)

Comment: Thanks for showing me that fiddle thing, that's a convenient tool. I just tried it and it seems your simulation works because the max(*_address) is applied on the actual address names (and Work starts with a W). I tried changing the final destination to "Another work" which made the query report the end address as "The store".

Comment: I really don't understand , the max(address) has no effect on the result.....the main thing here is the first_value and last_value....if you could show me the result with data in fiddle I could look into it...or else fine ..

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f23d15d574b3722f31e372e80abc16c

Comment: I added one more column, min(end_address), which should show what I mean :)

Comment: @Emil Fors, thanks to you and I realised now `last_value` works in a different way which is `The last_value() window function will pick the last value in the current frame. Without changing any of the frame defaults, this will be the current row.` so either we switch to `first_value` changing `order by start_time,end_time desc` or we need to add the window clause as I did now by updating the answer to tell `last_value` to consider complete result set as the `window frame`. Now I strongly believe it would work. Thanks again for the learning.

Comment: Final [db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0a7e167d4d8f3442a50adc4ef15d17c3)

Comment: Now it works! My specific problem is solved AND I've learned about window functions and fiddle. Thank you for taking the time to help :)